# Nested While loop in hangman

Tags: python, while-loop

I am creating a hangman game.Here are the conditions

- User will be given six chances for wrong choices
- If the letter was already entered, user will be notified that letter already exists (user will not be penalised for double wrong entry)

Now my question is :

- I want to display the message that "user lost the game" if the number of wrong guessed letters goes to 7 and exists the loop but it is not happening

here is my code:

```
print("Welcome to Hangman"
      "__________________")
word = "Python"
wordlist=list(word)
wordlist.sort()

print(wordlist)
print("Word's length is", len(word))
letter=" "
used_letter=[]
bad_letter=[]
guess=[]
tries=0
while len(bad_letter)<7:

    while guess != wordlist or letter !="exit":
        letter = input("Guess your letter:")
        if letter in word and letter not in used_letter:
            guess.append(letter)
            print("good guess")
        elif letter in used_letter:
            print("letter already used")
        else:
            bad_letter.append(letter)
            print("bad guess")
        used_letter.append(letter)
        tries+=1
        print("You have ",6 - len(bad_letter), " tries remaining")
        print(guess)
        print("You have made ",tries," tries so far")
        guess.sort()

    print("Thank you for playing the game, you guessed in ",tries," tries.")
    print("Your guessed word is", word)
print("you lost the game")
```

I am very new to python so i would appreciate help in basic concepts

Comment: Hi Zam! would you be able to post the full code with more proper formatting? seems like some of your code is not placed correctly within the code block and `bad_letter` is undefined

Comment: I've pasted full code @Stanley

Comment: Have the answers on this post been helpful? in that case it would be nice if you could mark the answer as correct, if not i will come back later tonight and see what i can do :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `while len(bad_letter) < loop` is never exiting because of the while loop below it which is checking for the right answer or exit entry runs forever.

What you should do is only have one master while loop which takes in a new input each time and then check to see if that input matches any of the conditions you are looking for.

You could structure it something like this:

```
bad_letter = []
tries = 0
found_word = False

while len(bad_letter) < 7:
    letter = input("Guess your letter:")
    if letter == 'exit':
        break  # Exit game loop

    if letter in word and letter not in used_letter:
        guess.append(letter)
        print("good guess")
    elif letter in used_letter:
        print("letter already used")
    else:
        bad_letter.append(letter)
        print("bad guess")

    used_letter.append(letter)
    tries+=1
    print("You have ", 6 - len(bad_letter), " tries remaining")
    print(guess)
    print("You have made ",tries," tries so far")
    guess.sort()

    if guess == wordlist:
        found_word = True
        break  # Exits the while loop

print("Thankyou for playing tha game, you guessed in ",tries," tries.")
print("Your guessed word is", word)
if found_word:
    print("You won")
else:
    print("you lost the game")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
word = 'Zam'
guesses = []
guesses_string = ''
bad_guesses = []
chances = 6

def one_letter(message=""):
    user_input = 'more than one letter'
    while len(user_input) > 1 or user_input == '':
        user_input = input(message)
    return user_input


while chances > 0:
    if sorted(word.lower()) == sorted(guesses_string.lower()):
        print("\nYou guessed every letter! (" + guesses_string + ")")
        break
    guess = one_letter("\nGuess a letter: ")
    if guess in guesses or guess in bad_guesses:
        print("You already guessed the letter " + guess + ".")
        continue
    elif guess.lower() in word.lower():
        print("Good guess " + guess + " is in the word!.")
        guesses.append(guess)
        guesses_string = ''.join(guesses)
        print("Letters guessed: " + guesses_string)
    else:
        print("Sorry, " + guess + " is not in the word.")
        bad_guesses.append(guess)
        chances -= 1
        print(str(chances) + " chances remaning.")

if chances == 0:
    print("\nGame Over, You Lose.")
else:
    word_guess = ''
    while word_guess.lower() != word.lower():
        word_guess = input("Guess the word: ('quit' to give up) ")    
        if word_guess.lower() == 'quit':
           print("You gave up, the word was " + word.title() + "!")
           break
    if word_guess.lower() == word.lower():
        print("\nCongratulations YOU WON! The word was "
            + word.title() + "!")
```

Hey there! I'm new to programming (week 2) and keep seeing these 'hangman' games popup, since today is my break from learning, I the goals you were trying to achieve and ran with it. 
Added some extra features in here such as breaking the loop if the all letters are guessed, and then asking the user to guess the final word.

**Notes**

There is a ton of Refactoring you could do with this(almost breaks my heart to post this raw form) but I just blurted it on on the go.
Also note that my original goal was to stick to your problem of not allowing the same letter to be entered twice. So this solution only works for words that contain no duplicate letters.

Hope this helps! When I get some time I'll Refactor it and update, best of luck!

**Updates**
Added `bad_guesses = []` allows to stop from entering bad guess twice.